# Container with std::vector and std::set properties ?

Tags: c++, c++11, containers

Is there a container in the C++ world that has these properties ?

- Elements are unique and ordered with the help of a customizable comparator
- provide an random access operator.

I'm currently collecting my data into a `std::set<C,COMPARATOR>` and afterwards do a `std::copy(_set.begin(),_set.end(),std::back_inserter(_vec))` to be able to have random access to the ordered collection. The size however might go into hundreds of millions.

Comment: Would a heap help ? You won't have total ordering, but will be able to pick the max element.

Comment: @Quentin no strict  ordering is essential

Comment: Are you going to be doing lots of insertions and/or deletions in the middle of the data? That's going to make a big difference in acceptable solutions. Your current solution could be bettered by adding to the vector directly and running `std::sort` on it, it should be slightly faster overall.

Comment: @MarkRansom The problem with sort on a vector is that it doesn't guarantee uniqueness. If I walk through the data I would like double inserts of the same key to be silently ignored.

Comment: @Oncaphillis If you only have relatively few duplicates, you can use [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) after `std::sort`. Btw, is is correct to say that your situation involves first building the data structure once and for all and that it is later only read from?

Comment: @screwnut No -- I expect many duplicates and no I expect many insert afterwards, deletes however are very unlikely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If Boost is an option, have a look at [`flat_set` in the Containers library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx).

The interface for `flat_set` is identical to that of `std::set` but it provides random access iterators, like `std::vector`:

```
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>

[...]

boost::container::flat_set<int> c;
c.insert(1);
c.insert(2);
c.insert(3);
c.insert(4);

// unfortunately, no operator[] on the container itself,
// but the iterator is random access
int third_element = c.begin()[2];
```

If you are stuck with the standard library, you can use a sorted `vector` for this purpose. The standard library actually offers a lot of algorithms in the `<algorithm>` header that allow you to do pretty much anything that you can do with a `set` with a sorted iterator range.

Comment: I'll have to look at the performance for insertion/deletion but I think this is it. boost is definitely an option

Comment: They provide a random access iterator but no `operator[]`? Wonder what the rationale is for that.

Comment: Well I had a test run with 10^6 random number inserts and it took sth. like 140 sec. Insertion into a std::set<int> with later copy into a std::vector<int> did it under 1sec. Since I'm not doing many insertion/deletions after initialization I think I stick with my solution. However I still take this answer as the proper solution to my initial question.

Comment: @Barry the semantic of [] is to access the container via a key/index but a set or flat_set doesn't have a key/index unless you say the value itself is the key/index. In this case the only valid assignment would be set[n] = n; and a read access doesn't make anything at all since the value you get back will always be the key itself.

Answer (score 1):

None that I am aware of. However, with hundreds of millions of elements and some ordered access you might want your memory representation to be compact and consecutive, which are even more requirements for your container class.

I'd go with `std::vector` and use the approach that you have described or any other sorting algorithm. You probably won't need your `std::set` afterwards, so you can free the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the standard C++ library, no. You either have `set`/`priority_queue` for ordering or `vector`/`deque` for random access.

But there's nothing to stop you from writing your own wrapper around `vector` which simply enforces ordering. It's not that much code at all. Some example functions:

```
template <typename T, typename COMP = std::less<T>>
class sorted_vec {
    std::vector<T> vec_;

public:
    // random access
    using iterator = typename std::vector<T>::iterator;
    T& operator[](size_t idx) { return vec_[idx]; }

    iterator begin() { return vec_.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return vec_.end(); }

    // insertion
    void push(const T& val) {
        vec_.insert(std::lower_bound(vec_.begin(), vec_.end(), COMP{}),
                    val);
    }
};
```

Comment: I'd also write the `const` version of `T& operator[]`, so you can pass by `const` reference.

Comment: @vsoftco Right, this is by no means an exhaustive list of functions (e.g. there's no `const_iterator`, etc.)